# Can Play 2.2.3 be packed as WAR and deployed in other servers?

Tags: playframework

I chanced upon play2war plugin instructions but, Usually end up with errors.
So, Please help me on how an application developed on play 2.2.3 can be deployed externally with out the help on in built netty server ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What errors are you getting using the Play2-war plugin?

Comment: Donovan, my error was "Server Access Error:Connection timed out" but now after correcting proxy settings in build file I was able to make it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

At time of writing there is no official way of deploying a Play 2 app to a Servlet/Java EE container. The only way to do this is using the [Play2-war](https://github.com/play2war/play2-war-plugin) plugin you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks Arjan :) I followed the instructions on 
http://blog.jelastic.com/2013/07/02/play-2-web-application-deployment-tutorial/ and now I'm able to make a war, my server connection error was due to proxy settings and now I'm able to make a war